# CSS {word-wrap: break-word} won't work in :before selector

Tags: css, word-wrap

I used the [responsive table solution found here](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/).

I added `word-wrap: break-word`, but it is not working for the table below:

[image]

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SRD75/0gn4md2b/6/)

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><strong>MTP 1: Acute Symptomatic</strong></td>
<td><strong>MTP 2: Acute and Chronic Symptomatic</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1 x 60 minutes session weekly for 6 weeks at <span style="color: #ff0000;">$420</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="color: #ff00ff;">save $60</span></td>
<td>Fortnightly 1 x 60 minutes session for 11 weeks at <span style="color: #ff0000;">$450</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="color: #ff00ff;">save $30</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1 x 90 minutes session weekly for 6 weeks at&nbsp;<span style="color: #ff0000;">$630</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="color: #ff00ff;">save $60</span></td>
<td>Fortnightly 1 x 90 minutes session for 11 weeks at <span style="color: #ff0000;">$660</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="color: #ff00ff;">save $30</span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content table tbody {border-top: 1px solid #ccc;}
#content table tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background: #eee;
}
#content tr td {
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  #content td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "MTP 1: Acute Symptomatic"; word-wrap: break-word;}
  #content td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "MTP 2: Acute and Chronic Symptomatic"; word-wrap: break-word;}

    #content table tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
        background: transparent;
    }

    /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
    #content table, #content thead, #content tbody, #content th, #content td, #content tr { 
        display: block; 
    }

    /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
    #content thead tr, #content tr:nth-of-type(1) { 
        position: absolute;
        top: -9999px;
        left: -9999px;
    }

    #content tr { border: 1px solid #ccc; }

    #content td { 
        /* Behave  like a "row" */
        border: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; 
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 50%; 
        width: 50%;
        max-width: 50%;
        min-height: 39px;
        line-height: 1.5em;
    }
    #content #post-4818 td:nth-of-type(1) {
        background-color: #FFC384;
    }

    #content td:before { 
        /* Now like a table header */
        position: absolute;
        /* Top/left values mimic padding */
        top: 6px;
        left: 6px;
        width: 45%; 
        padding-right: 10px; 
        white-space: nowrap;
    }  
}
```

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it, the only thing you need to do is to remove the `white-space: nowrap;` from this rule

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0gn4md2b/8/)

```
#content td:before { 
    /* Now like a table header */
    position: absolute;
    /* Top/left values mimic padding */
    top: 6px;
    left: 6px;
    width: 45%; 
    padding-right: 10px; 
    /*  white-space: nowrap;          commented out    */
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I never saw that `white-space: nowrap;`. That came with the [example code](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/) I used.

Answer (score 2):

Replace your `#content td:before` with this css -

```
#content td:before { 
    /* Now like a table header */
    position: absolute;
    /* Top/left values mimic padding */
    top: 6px;
    left: 6px;
    width: 45%; 
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Then add this css -

```
.wrapword{
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
  white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
  white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
  white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
  word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
  white-space: -webkit-pre-wrap; /* Newer versions of Chrome/Safari*/
  white-space: normal;
}
```

And finally add a class `wrapword` to your `tbody` like this -

```
<tbody class="wrapword">
```

Here's [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0gn4md2b/7/)

Comment: Thanks Rehban. I'll use LGSon's simpler solution below.

Comment: No problem man, I did the same thing but added word wrap that supports all browsers..

Comment: Ahhh. Why can't I add your `.wrapword` rules be added to `#content td:before`? That would be safer for me, in case my client edits the Wordpress page, and loses the `<tbody class="wrapword">` in the process.

Comment: I recommend you to add those rules in different class so that whenever or wherever you require to wrap text, just add the wrap word class to the tag, and you're good to go.. And it's your wish where you want to add those rules..

Comment: Being coding for 20 years, I never saw those prefixed values. From where did you get them ? ... and as well, by having the `white-space: normal` last in that rule, takes out all the rest so no point having them in there in the first place, and as this is the default, no need to add it just in case either

Comment: Thanks. I've decided to take your advice. I'm using Chrome 50.0.2661.87 m on Windows (the latest version), and I see [invalid property value](https://imgur.com/UrfUdVO) for `white-space: -webkit-pre-wrap;` - [live page](http://vivesco-mhf.com.au/vivesco-mobile-health-fitness-prices/)

Comment: @Steve Yepp, and I just needed to comment on this, as I'm pretty sure they don't exist, so users think they need to use them

Comment: Thanks @LGSon. I'll remove `white-space: -webkit-pre-wrap;`.  Rehban, see [this search](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=-webkit-pre-wrap)

Comment: @Steve That goes for all the hyphen `-` prefixed values ... none exists

Comment: Thanks. Someone sent it to me when I was working on a project. I thought it does exist at that time. I removed it now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks @LGSon. Maybe let the person know it doesn't exist Rehban?